# Swift MacApp - fire click event not working

Tags: swift

I'm a beginner to Swift MacApp programming, I'm trying to create an easy app for my own use to automate my manual actions. I try to fire the left mouse button click without success, even though the moving mouse working just fine.

```
func MouseClick(cursorLocation p0: CGPoint) {
    print("MouseClick", p0);
    usleep(useconds_t(Int.random(in: 30000..<100000)))
    
    if (!alreadyClicked){
        print("Do click again")
        alreadyClicked = true;
        MouseClick(cursorLocation: p0);
    }
    
    MoveCursor(cursorLocation: p0);
    
    CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .mouseMoved,    mouseCursorPosition: p0, mouseButton: .left)?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    usleep(50000)
    CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseUp,    mouseCursorPosition: p0, mouseButton: .left)?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    usleep(50000)
    CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseUp,      mouseCursorPosition: p0, mouseButton: .left)?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
}
```

I have heard that MacApps are running in a Sandbox environment, I followed few tutorials but after doing screenshots from my application all I can see is desktop and application window.

That's my second question, how to run my Application on 'normal' system view? Also every time I run my application I got a permission window if I allow doing screenshots, is it possible to give permission to do screenshots?. I will use this application only on my local Mac if it matters.

I'm using macOS Big Sur (11.5.2), Swift Language Version: Swift 5

Comment: Ask one question at a time.

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because you're blocking the run loop by using `usleep`. You need a way to do a non-block delay, such as with a Timer, Combine TimerPublisher, or the new Async/await feature.

Comment: @Alexander `usleep(50000)` is a 0.05 sec. delay and the runloop can handle it.

Comment: @Willeke oh yeah, true

Comment: Another thing: using `?.` makes no sense in this context. If you misconfigured your CGEvent’s initialisation, *you would want to know*. Currently, in such a case, your program would silently do nothing, hiding a possible error.

Comment: @Alexander I created new project with just this snipped but still no luck. I had to manually disable and enable permission to Accessibility for this application, thanks for idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mouse click is a mouse-down and a mouse-up instead of two mouse-ups.

```
CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseDown,
    mouseCursorPosition: p0, mouseButton: .left)?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
usleep(50000)
CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseUp,
    mouseCursorPosition: p0, mouseButton: .left)?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
```

Comment: Yes that was typo from copying code (i had few crazy ideas, why its not working). Solution for me was @Alexander idea about "you misconfigured your CGEvent’s initialisation" i had manually disable and enable permission to Accessibility for this application....

Comment: @Buzka91 Let this be a lesson into the dangers of `?.`. "crashing" sounds bad, but the benign-seeming alternative of "silently do nothing" turns to have cost you several hours of frustrating debugging!